# Adding My App to The Gallery App menu

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-gallery

I am trying to set my application what will be a tool to edit pictures, to the menu in the gallery app of the android phone. I know it should go with the intent-filter but I can not get it to work.

```
        <activity android:name=".Compass" android:label="@string/main_compass_tool_button">
        <intent-filter android:label= "@string/main_compass_tool_button">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SHARE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am confused by your question. Are you trying to make your app one of the options to manage pictures? Or are you trying to make your app show up in the normal list of apps accessible from the home screen? Please word your question a little more clearly.

Answer (score 5):

The reason it is not working is because the `action` should be

```
android.intent.action.SEND
```

Not

```
android.intent.action.SHARE
```

I've mixed up the two also. `SHARE` is what you are supposed to show in the interface when sending a `SEND` intent - there is no `SHARE` intent.

Comment: Hope you still need this answer, it's been a few weeks since you asked.